# CSS background-image SVG capped on edges

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use the [dashed border generator](https://kovart.github.io/dashed-border-generator) but in the resulting SVG I noticed the edges are capped, any ideas how to avoid this?

```css
.block {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='none' rx='100%25' ry='100%25' stroke='%238B98A6' stroke-width='9' stroke-dasharray='2%2c 8' stroke-dashoffset='16' stroke-linecap='butt'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
```

Comment: because you're drawing outside the edge of your canvas. Your rect is 100% wide and then you add a stroke to it which makes it 100% + 9px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding `border-radius` property ?.

```css
.block {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg width='100%25' height='100%25' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='none' rx='100%25' ry='100%25' stroke='%238B98A6' stroke-width='9' stroke-dasharray='2%2c 8' stroke-dashoffset='16' stroke-linecap='butt'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
```